# change condition variable in probability mass function

Tags: probability

I have the following conditional and marginal densities/mass functions: $p(y|x_1,x_2)$, $p(y)$, $p(x_1,x_2)=p(x_1)p(x_2)$, and $p(f(x_1,x_2))$.

(The notation might be a bit loose since $y$ is discrete binary and $x_i$ is continuous. This is an engineering problem.)

I want to compute $p(y|f(x_1,x_2))$. Is it possible?

In this case $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1\times x_2$, which may help, but I'd prefer a general solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning up your notation, let's instead use $p_?$ for mass functions, $f_{?}$ for density functions, and so on, and $g$ for the other function.   Also we will use random variables $X, Y, Z$ to save typing subscripts of subscripts. ($X=X_1, Z=X_2$)

So you have $p_Y(y), p_{Y\mid X, Z}(y\mid x, z), f_{X,Z}(x,z)= f_X(x)f_Z(z), g(X,Z)=X\cdot Z$ and $f_{g(X,Z)}(u)$.

$$p_{Y\mid g(X,Z)}(y\mid u) = \iint\limits_{\{g(x,z)=u\}} p_{Y\mid X,Z}(y\mid x, z) \; f_{X,Z\mid g(X,Z)}(x,z\mid u) \operatorname d z\operatorname d x\\ = \int\limits_{\Bbb R} \lvert x\rvert^{-1} p_{Y\mid X,Z}(y\mid x,u/x)\,f_{X,Z\mid XZ}(x,u/x\mid u)\operatorname d x$$

---

Note: $f_{X,Z\mid XZ}(x,z\mid u) = \dfrac{f_{X,Z}(x,z)\;\mathbf 1_{xz=u}}{\int_{\Bbb R} \lvert x\rvert^{-1} f_{X,Z}(x, u/x) \operatorname d x}$

---

Keyword: "[product distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution)"

Comment: In the denominator of the note, can I replace $x$ with an unused variable, say $w$?

Comment: When I substitute $f_{X,Z∣XZ}(x,z∣u)$ into the main expression, can I simply replace $z$ with $u/x$ and remove the indicator function? I understand everything else - thanks so much.

Comment: @Adriel Yes, that is the way to proceed.